# Laravel validation no space allowed for username

Tags: validation, laravel

I have a little problem in laravel validation request. I want to reject username with space like `foo bar`. I just want to allow `foobar` without space. Right now my rule is `required|unique:user_detail,username`. What rule should i use? thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can extend the validator with your own custom rules:

```
Validator::extend('without_spaces', function($attr, $value){
    return preg_match('/^\S*$/u', $value);
});
```

Then just use as any other rule:

```
required|without_spaces|unique:user_detail,username
```

Checkout the docs on custom validation rules:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: use regex in rules instead of create new custom validation. `'username' => 'required|regex:/^\S*$/u',`

Comment: This simply removes spaces. Periods, commas, or other characters can still be inserted

Answer (score 68):

Why don't you use `alpha_dash` [rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-alpha-dash)?

```
required|alpha_dash|unique:user_detail,username
```

From the documentation:

> The field under validation may have alpha-numeric characters, as well
>   as dashes and underscores.

And it doesn't allow spaces.

Comment: alpha will not allow underscores for example.

Comment: alpha_dash can work, it all depends on the characters you want to allow. String like: "(╯°□°）╯" will fail alpha_dash validation too.

Comment: Of course it will. Do you read alpha_dash docs? _The field under validation may have alpha-numeric characters, as well as dashes and underscores._

Comment: Try it yourself alpha_dash doesn't allow parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

You should use regular expression with your validation.

PHP :

```
required|unique:user_detail,username,'regex:/\s/'
```

Comment: Thanks! But it should be `regex:/^\S*$/u`

Answer (score 2):

Laravel validation for username or subdomain

```
    "subdomain" => [
        "regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/",
        "required", "min:3","max:20","unique:subdomains",
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expressions with your validation.

Laravel:

```
'domain' => 'required|max:255|unique:users|regex:/(^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*$)/u',
```

Answer (score 0):

The assumption is that a username can contain either (only alphabetic letters) or a mixture of (alphabetic letters and numbers).

In that case, the rules below should work.
(for alphabetic letters) -> `['username' => 'alpha']` //eg `johndoe`
(for alphabetic letters and numbers) -> `['username' => 'alpha_num']` //eg `johndoe123`